# I cannot seem to get my sprite to rotate using controls

Tags: python, pygame, transform

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    # currently this img stuff is a filler until I am bothered to do graphics or someone is willing to do them
    self.image = player_img
    self.image0 = new_player_img
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.pos = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
    self.vel = vec(0, 0)
    self.acc = vec(0, 0)
    self.rot = 0
    self.rot_speed = vec(14, -14)
    self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()

def rotate(self):
    rkeys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if rkeys[pygame.K_z]:
        self.rot_speed.x = self.rot
    if rkeys[pygame.K_c]:
        self.rot_speed.y = self.rot

    pygame.transform.rotate(self.image0, self.rot)
    self.image = self.image0


def update(self):
    self.acc = vec(0, 0)
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.acc.y = -PLAYER_ACC
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.acc.y = PLAYER_ACC

    #apply translations
    self.acc += self.vel * PLAYER_FRICTION
    self.vel += self.acc
    self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc
    self.image0 = self.image
    self.rotate()

    # wrapping around the screen for now until ive worked out a playing area
    if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
        self.pos.x = 0
    if self.pos.x < 0:
        self.pos.x = WIDTH
    if self.pos.y > HEIGHT:
        self.pos.y = 0
    if self.pos.y < 0:
        self.pos.y = HEIGHT

    self.rect.center = self.pos
```

I dont know why but for some reason the rotate function does nothing and I am clearly rotating and setting the player image as the rotated image. Can anyone help me with this? The All i need it for the sprite to be rotated by the user so I can "Drive" the sprite like a car.

Comment: first use `print()` to check if function is executed, and if variables changes values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pygame.transform.rotate` function returns a new surface and doesn't modify the original image, so you have to assign it to the `self.image` attribute. Afterwards you have to create a new rect with `self.image.get_rect` so that the sprite stays centered.

The next problem is the rotation speed. The `rot` attribute is the current angle which you have to update by the `rot_speed` each frame, e.g. `self.rot += self.rot_speed`.

I'd also move the event handling to the update method and just pass the desired `rot_speed` to the `rotate` method.

In the `update` method the `self.acc += self.vel * PLAYER_FRICTION` and `self.image0 = self.image` were causing erroneous behavior, so I removed them.

Here's a fixed minimal and complete version:

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2 as Vec

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 640, 480
PLAYER_FRICTION = .95
PLAYER_ACC = .1

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.image0 = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = Vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = Vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = Vec(0, 0)
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = 3
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self, rot_speed):
        self.rot += rot_speed  # Change `self.rot` (the angle).
        # Rotate the original image.
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image0, self.rot)
        # Get a new rect with the center of the old rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def update(self):
        self.acc = Vec(0, 0)
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.acc.x = PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.acc.y = -PLAYER_ACC
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.acc.y = PLAYER_ACC
        # Call self.rotate with the desired speed.
        if keys[pygame.K_z]:
            self.rotate(self.rot_speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_c]:
            self.rotate(-self.rot_speed)

        # apply translations
        self.vel += self.acc
        self.vel *= PLAYER_FRICTION
        self.pos += self.vel + 0.5 * self.acc

        # wrapping around the screen
        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = 0
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH
        if self.pos.y > HEIGHT:
            self.pos.y = 0
        if self.pos.y < 0:
            self.pos.y = HEIGHT

        self.rect.center = self.pos


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Player())

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

---

If you want to move the object like a car, you have to change a few more things. I'd set the `self.acc` to the desired value and then just add it to the `self.vel` in the update method if the UP or DOWN keys get pressed. Then you also have to rotate the `self.acc` and `self.vel` vectors in the `rotate` method and it works as desired.

```
import pygame
from pygame.math import Vector2 as Vec

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
PLAYER_FRICTION = .95

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((30, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue1'))
        self.image0 = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos = Vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.vel = Vec(0, 0)
        self.acc = Vec(0, -1)
        self.rot = 0
        self.rot_speed = 3
        self.last_update = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    def rotate(self, rot_speed):
        self.rot += rot_speed  # Change `self.rot` (the angle).
        self.acc.rotate_ip(-rot_speed)
        self.vel.rotate_ip(-rot_speed)
        # Rotate the original image.
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image0, self.rot)
        # Get a new rect with the center of the old rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        # Call self.rotate with the desired speed.
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rotate(self.rot_speed)
        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rotate(-self.rot_speed)
        # Accelerate if UP or DOWN get pressed.
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.vel += self.acc
        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.vel += self.acc

        pygame.display.set_caption('Vel {}, Acc: {}'.format(self.vel, self.acc))
        # apply translations
        self.vel *= PLAYER_FRICTION
        self.pos += self.vel

        # wrapping around the screen
        if self.pos.x > WIDTH:
            self.pos.x = 0
        if self.pos.x < 0:
            self.pos.x = WIDTH
        if self.pos.y > HEIGHT:
            self.pos.y = 0
        if self.pos.y < 0:
            self.pos.y = HEIGHT

        self.rect.center = self.pos


def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(Player())

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Comment: this is the exact thing i wanted thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

`rotate(image)` doesn't change original `image` but it returns new one so you have to assign it to variable

```
self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image0, self.rot)
```

---

BTW: you shouldn't assign `image` to `image0`

```
self.image0 = self.image
```

because this way you loose original `image0` which you should keep unchanged and use to generate rotated image. Using always original `image0` to create rotated one you should get better looking image then rotating `image`.